# Django wsgi.py Setting Email Environment Variables Causing Internal Server Error No Logging

Tags: python, django, apache, email

I am setting up a test email account in my Django saleor app on a test system.

The test system is running Django in a virtualenv using apache2/mod_wsgi

```
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 8, 7, 'final', 0)
```

The email section of my settings.py file contains the following:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST")
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
EMAIL_HOST_PORT = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_PORT")
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.environ.get('DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL')
```

On my local system I have the following environment variables set vis. email:

```
EMAIL_HOST="smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER="name@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="doublesecret"
EMAIL_HOST_PORT=587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL="name@gmail.com"
```

I have tested this with gmail's smtp on my local system and it works fine.

My wsgi.py on the remote host running apache is:

```
import os
import sys
import site

os.environ.setdefault("EMAIL_HOST", "smtp.gmail.com")
os.environ.setdefault("EMAIL_HOST_USER", "name@gmail.com")
os.environ.setdefault("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD", "doublesecret")
os.environ.setdefault("EMAIL_HOST_PORT", 587)
os.environ.setdefault("DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL", "name@gmail.com")

site.addsitedir("/home/user/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
os.environ.setdefault("SECRET_KEY", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaayyyyylmao")
os.environ.setdefault("MYSQL_DB_URL", "mysql://user:passwordo@myhost-dev.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/saleor")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "saleor.settings")
project = "/home/user/project/saleor"
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
sys.path.append(workspace)

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When attempting to send a request_email_confirmation I'm greeted with an internal server error message.

I'm sure I'm missing some bit about the order the environment variables are declared, or where they are declared. For obvious reasons, I'd rather not hardcode the variables into my settings.py.

Clues on why this is happening? More importantly, clues on how to properly troubleshoot on apache/mod_wsgi/django when I'm too noobed to log things correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do to debug first:

change settings like `os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST")` to `os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST", 'proper settings')` and see if the error is your django instance not able to get the env values.

Secondly, depends on how you setup apache and wsgi, also assuming you haven't setup the `LOGGING` settings, your error log will most ending up inside `/var/log/apache/`

Comment: Turns out I was doing some very shallow stupid with os.environ.setdefault: It wants strings. :-) Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am, apparently, a bit of an idiot.

I added the following to wsgi.py:

```
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
```

And set

```
LogLevel info
```

in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, which put useful error messages into /var/log/apache2/error.log

Which revealed:

```
TypeError: must be string, not int
```

Yes, I airheaded putting quotes around EMAIL_HOST_PORT's value!

```
os.environ.setdefault("EMAIL_HOST_PORT", "587")
```

Is correct. I can now successfully send email.